# Azure Mobile Services Insert function

Tags: sql, ms-access, mobile, azure

Is it possible to handling handling external inserts/updates to Azure SQL Database from Azure Mobile Services (INSERT, UPDATE, directly to db and etc.)
I know about scripting. All tables working fine, and visible from Mobile Service manage center. 
I need to handle events like direct SQL requests to DB from DB management portal or Azure Web sites, without direct requests to Mobile Service (REST API, and etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the question how to execute SQL commands from a mobile device directly against the database (SQL Database) without first going through the REST API and scripting layer Mobile Services provides?

If so, then the answer is essentially no. The mobile device needs some way to communicate with the database, it uses the API and scripting layer to do this.  Of course, you could build your own web service layer that then works with the database.  But, this layer is what Mobile Services is providing for you out-of-the-box.

However, if the question is can you issue SQL commands against the database using tools like SQL Server Management Studio or even other web sites, then the answer is yes.  The SQL Database which Mobile Services provides is a regular SQL Database.  You have full control over it.  You can connect to it and issue commands just like you would with SQL Database (via an ORM or direct SQL statements).

Comment: Looks like i made little misformed question.
I ask, is it possible to handle SQL DB operations like INSERT or UPDATE from Mobile Services Scripting. Without manual REST API calls.

Comment: Using the mssql object in the server side scripts, you should be able to execute pretty much whatever SQL command you want.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554212.aspx.  Does that help?